# How to debug TSQL on SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, debugging

How can I debug TSQL on SQL Server 2005 instance?

Thanks.

Comment: In what environment? IF you have vis studio, open up server explorer attach to the db in question, select what db item you would like to debug and then attach a break point where you need to in the file.  However, this kind of debugging leaves a lot to be desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 Guys From Rolla has a really good tutorial on using Visual Studio to debug SQL Server 2k5 Stored Procedures:

[4GuysFromRolla.com: Debugging SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedures in Visual Studio](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102846/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051607-1.aspx)

Unfortunately, as far as I know, Visual Studio is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use print statements or log status updates in a table.